# SQL Server DB size - why is it so large?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

I am building a database which contains about 30 tables:

- The largest amount of columns in a table is about 15.
- For datatypes I am mostly using VarChar(50) for text
- and Int og SmallInt for numbers.
- Identity columns is Uniqueidentifiers

I have been testing a bit filling in data and deleting
again. I have no deleted all data, so everey table is empty.
But, if I look inside the properties of the database in 
Management Studio, the size says 221,38 MB!

How comes that? Please help, I am getting notifications
from my hosting company that I am exceeding my limits .

Best regards,
:-)

Comment: I suspect the Transaction Logs.  Read up on back-ups... That can shrink them down in size.

Comment: And just shrink it. Removing the data will not shrink the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that you look first at the recovery mode for the database.  By default, the recovery mode is FULL.  This fills the log file with all transactions that you perform, never deleting them until you do a backup.

To change the recovery mode, right click on the database and choose Properties.  In the properties list, choose the Options (on the right hand pane).  Then change the "Recovery model" to Simple.

You probably also want to shrink your files.  To do this, right click on the database and choose Tasks --> Shrink --> Files.  You can shrink both the data file and the log file, by changing the "File Type" option in the middle.

Martin's comment is quite interesting.  Even if the log file is in auto-truncate mode, you still have the issue of deletes being logged.  If you created large-ish tables, the log file will still expand and the space not recovered until you truncate the file.  You can get around this by using `TRUNCATE` rathe than `DELETE`:

```
truncate table <table>
```

does not log every record being deleted (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx).

```
delete * from table
```

logs every record.

Comment: By default the recovery mode is full but this doesn't kick in until a full backup has been taken once. [until then it is in auto-truncate mode](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2008/11/30/when-is-full-recovery-not-really-full-recovery.aspx)

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . This is very interesting.  I cannot find a reference in the SQL Server documentation itself; do you know if this is mentioned there?  In any case, my answer may only be appropriate if the database has ever had a full back up.

Comment: Thank you! Setting the recovery mode to simple and shrinking the database after that reduced the whole thing to 3 mb :-)

I could not access it via the Management Studio because of user rights, but this script helped me out:

ALTER DATABASE [Hxxx_xxxxxxxxxx] SET RECOVERY simple
Go
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE(N'Hxxx_xxxxxxxxxx' )
Go

Answer (score 4):

As you do inserts, updates, deletes, and design changes a log file with every transaction, and a whole bunch of other data is created.  This transaction log is a required component of a SQL Server database, and thus cannot be disabled in any available settings.

Below is an article from Microsoft on doing backups to shrink the transaction logs generated by SQL Server.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also, are you indexing your columns?  Indexes that consist of several columns on tables with a high row count can become unnecessarily large, especially if you are just doing tests.  Try just having a single clustered index on only one column per table.

You may also want to learn about table statistics.  They help your indexes out and also help you perform queries like SELECT DISTINCT, or SELECT COUNT(*), etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx

Finally, you will need to upgrade your storage allocation for the SQL Server database.  The more you use it, the faster it will want to grow.